# Trying to get property of non-object on query data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a table with column code ,program_string_id,practice_string_id

```
$project = db::table('project as p')->where('p.code',$asset_request->project_code);
$project_type = $project->select('p.practice_string_id','p.program_string_id')->first();
```

`print_r($project_type)` gives `stdClass Object ( [practice_string_id] => PRACTICE0019 [program_string_id] => )`

`print_r($project_type->practice_string_id);` returns

> Trying to get property of non-object.

How to get the value in laravel query

Answer (score 1):

you can write single query like this and just debug weather you are getting correct code and correct data

```
 $project_type = DB::table('project')
                  ->where('code',$asset_request->project_code)
                  ->select('practice_string_id','program_string_id')
                  ->first();
   dd($asset_request->project_code,$project_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $project_type = DB::table('project')
                  ->where('code',$asset_request->project_code)
                  ->select('project.*')
                  ->first();
   dd($project_type);
```